# How to update value of var in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple project about connect between java server and javascript client via websocket.
Here my HTML file:

```
<body>

    <h3>Demo WebSocket</h3>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var arr;
        var websocket;
        connect();
        function connect() {
            websocket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4444');

            websocket.onopen = function () {
                var i = (typeof websocket != 'undefined' && websocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN);
                textAreaMessage.value += "Server  ..." + i + "\n";
            };
            websocket.onmessage = function (message) { processMessage(message); };
            websocket.onclose = function (message) { processClose(message); };
            websocket.onerror = function (message) { processError(message); };
        }
        function disconnect() {
            websocket.close();
        }

        function processOpen(message) {
        }
        function processMessage(message) {
            console.log(message);
            arr = JSON.parse(message.data)
            textAreaMessage.value += "Response From Server ==> " + arr[0] + " \n";
        }
        function processClose(message) {
            textAreaMessage.value += "Server Disconnect... \n";
        }
        function processError(message) {
            textAreaMessage.value += "Error... " + message + " \n";
        }
        function sendMessage() {
            if (typeof websocket != 'undefined' && websocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
                websocket.send(textMessage.value);
                textAreaMessage.value += "Send to Server ==> " + textMessage.value + " \n";
                textMessage.value = "";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

when server send String via websocket to client, value of massage will store in `mesage.data` but i converted it to JavaScript object use `arr = JSON.parse(message.data)`
And then i `conole.log(arr)` and i see:

[image]

and I get each element of arr via index like: `arr[index]`.
The important thing is when the new value come via websocket then the value of element also change. I want display the value of element in page and its displayed value automatically changes when its value is changed.
Somebody can help me?
Sorry about my grammar.
Thank you so much!

Comment: First of all, you should add `var textAreaMessage = document.getElementById("textAreaMessage")`.

Comment: I think what you are trying to to do is `textAreaMessage.innerHTML += ...;`. This will write the string 'Response from server' in the textbox. If you want to re render the entire content of the textbox (that is, replace whatever is in it with the new data) just assign instead of concatenating like this `textAreaMessage.innerHTML = ...;`. The `...` must be replaced by proper JS code you want.